ABP Proxy Names
I am a bit new to ABP application framework. I have created a number of entities and razor pages that are working as expected. However one of my Entities is Called BloodGroup. When I try to a use the Proxy opyt.schoolManager.bloodgroups.bloodgroup.getList it does not work, I have tried to use opyt.schoolManager.blood-groups.blood-group.getList it does not work while for
opyt.schoolManager.relationships.relationship.getList it works perfectly.
I have also noticed that if you look at the swagger document the api looks https://localhost:44373/api/app/blood-group.
I just would like to know the proxy naming convention or if there is a way to disctate it.
Thanks  In Advance

ASP.NET Boilerplate ([tag:aspnetboilerplate]) or ABP Framework (abp.io / [tag:abp])?

The question should be updated to include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

I got the answer. After browsing through the internet I found that it should have been as below:
opyt.schoolManager.bloodGroups.bloodGroup.getList.
After I changed it then it was OK. Thank you all.
